# combobox error at compile time

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I want the combobox to store the name from database at runtime,so i creted a list but combobox is displaying an error...

```
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
                Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM company");
                i=0;
                while(rs.next()) {
                    s.add(rs.getString("Name"));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {             {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,ex);
            }
            cb=new JComboBox(s);
        }
```

Comment: "is displaying an error" is never enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: 30 seconds reading the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) would have at least told you why you had an error

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are right , but I saw his profile and he hasn't accepted any answers yet , even though they were helpful !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probable problem is that you are passing a `List<String>` reference to the [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) . One correct way to do this will be to convert the `List<String> s` to a `String[]` array and pass it to the [constructor: JComboBox(E[] items)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#constructor_detail)

```
 new JComboBox(s.toArray(new String[s.size()]));
```

Read also [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)